# Random value from Enum doesn't work as I would like it to

Tags: c#, random, enums

I'm using this code to find random values from my enum:

```
public cards chooseFromDeck()
{
    var random = new Random();
    return (cards)random.Next(cards.GetNames(typeof(cards)).Length);
}
```

and this is my Enum:

```
public enum cards
{Ace=1,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight,Nine,Ten,Jack=10,Queen=10,King=10}
```

And I have 2 problems with this.

1. It somehow picks up "0" as a value, which I don't understand since I have my Ace marked as "1".
2. The problem is that it doesn't pick Jack, Queen, and King at all, if I remove the "=10" from them all it works, but then the values are 11,12,13. What way should I use to add value "10" to Jack, Queen, and King?

Comment: The short answer - `enum` is the wrong data structure for this. You won't be able to distinguish Jack from King with your code. What you should do is create a `Card` class with a `Name` and a `Score`. Add multiple of these to a `List<Card>` then randomly choose from that list.

Answer (score 1):

1. The min value of the random next function is 0, therefore, you need to change the `minValue` of the random to be 1:

   ```
    return (cards)random.Next(1, cards.GetNames(typeof(cards)).Length);
   ```
2. This is not possible to do it with an enum. I would recommend you to use an array instead, with 4 times the option 10. The idea of writing 4 times the number 10 is to give a bigger chance to get 10 in the random function (as 10 stands for 4 different cards).

   ```
   readonly int[] cardNumbers = 
       new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10 };

   public int chooseFromDeck()
   {
       var random = new Random();
       return random.Next(1, cardNumbers.Length);
   }
   ```

As a side note, you are not using the Random function correctly and also this is not a secured function. You can read more about it [here](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Random).

Comment: Works for the "0", but not for the J,Q,K. I think I found the problem I just don't know how to fix it. When im returning random value, it chooses random number from 1 to 13, but in my enum theres 13 values, but last 4 have value 10 so I think thats why it wont register J,Q,K (when Random chooses 11 to 13)

Comment: @Damianhar Have you tried to work with int array instead of the enum? Look at the example I wrote in bullet 2. It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the key thing is assigning the same value (in your case: 10) to different enum members will not work in your case. So with your enum (with value 10 to Jack, Queen, King), if you do simple test by executing below line, you will get wrong value.

```
cards c2 = cards.Queen;
Console.WriteLine(c2); // outputs Ten
```

So the best thing, you can do is, remove assigning value 10 to multiple enum members (it will definitely trip you in future, if you keep) and write a method which will change the value to 10 when you use the enum. For example:

```
public enum cards {
    Ace = 1,
    Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen , King
}

private cards chooseFromDeck() {
    Random random = new Random();
    int rNum = random.Next(1, 13);
    return (cards)rNum;
}

private int GetCardsValue(cards c) {
        int value;
        switch (c) {
            case cards.Jack:
            case cards.King:
            case cards.Queen:
                value = 10;
                break;
            default:
                value = (int)c;
                break;
        }
        return value;
}
```

OR create a Extension method:

```
public static class Extensions 
{
    public static int GetValue(this cards c) {
        int value;
        switch (c) {
            case cards.Jack:
            case cards.King:
            case cards.Queen:
                value = 10;
                break;
            default:
                value = (int)c;
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

and use it as:

```
private void SomeMethod() {
    cards c = chooseFromDeck();
    int cval = c.GetValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public static class Enum
{
    private static int Random(int start, int end) =>
        new Random().Next(start, end);

    private static System.Array GetArray<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible =>
        System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));

    public static int GetSize<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible =>
        GetArray<T>().Length;

    public static int GetValue<T>(this T @enum) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException($"{typeof(T)} is not enum");
        return (int)(object)@enum;
    }

    public static int GetIndex<T>(this T @enum) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsEnum) throw new ArgumentException($"{typeof(T)} is not enum");
        return System.Array.IndexOf(GetArray<T>(), @enum);
    }

    /// index to enum
    public static T GetEnum<T>(this int index) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        var array = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(T));
        return (T)array.GetValue(index);
    }

    /// [0,Length)
    public static T Random<T>() where T : struct, IConvertible =>
        Random(0, GetSize<T>()).GetEnum<T>();

    /// [start,end]
    public static T Random<T>(T start, T end) where T : struct, IConvertible =>
        Random<T>(start.GetIndex(), end.GetIndex() + 1);

    /// [start,end)
    public static T Random<T>(int start, int end) where T : struct, IConvertible
    {
        var size = GetSize<T>();
        if (start < 0) start = 0;
        if (end > size) end = size;
        return Random(start, end).GetEnum<T>();
    }
}
```

---

enum

```cs
// value
public enum EnumShape // length = 8
{
    None,     // 0
    Direct,   // 1
    Square,   // 2
    Cross,    // 3
    Circle,   // 4
    BigSquare,// 5
    BigCross, // 6
    BigCircle,// 7
}

public enum EnumInNeedShape // length = 5
{
    None,                      // 0
    Square = EnumShape.Square, // 2
    Cross = EnumShape.Cross,   // 3
    Circle = EnumShape.Circle, // 4
    Triangle = 10,             // 10
}
```

---

test GetEnum

```cs
class Test{
    pubilc void Test(){
        0.GetEnum<EnumShape>();// None
        1.GetEnum<EnumShape>();// Square
        2.GetEnum<EnumShape>();// Cross
        3.GetEnum<EnumShape>();// Circle
        4.GetEnum<EnumShape>();// Triangle


        10.GetEnum<EnumShape>();// throw IndexOutOfRangeException
    }
}
```

---

test GetValue, GetRandom

```cs
public class Test
{
    pubilc void Test()
    {
        $"Square {(int)EnumInNeedShape.Square}".LogLine(); // 2
        $"Square {(int)EnumInNeedShape.Circle}".LogLine(); // 4

        EnumInNeedShape.Triangle.GetValue().LogLine(); // 10
        EnumInNeedShape.Triangle.GetIndex().LogLine(); // 4
        Enum.Random(EnumInNeedShape.None, EnumInNeedShape.Triangle).LogLine(); // [None, Triangle]
        Enum.Random(EnumShape.None, EnumShape.AltCircle).LogLine(); // [None, AltCircle]
        Enum.Random<EnumShape>(0, 9).LogLine(); // [None, AltCircle]
        Enum.Random(EnumInNeedShape.Square, EnumInNeedShape.Circle).LogLine(); // [Square, Circle]
        Enum.Random(EnumInNeedShape.Cross, EnumInNeedShape.Triangle).LogLine(); // [Cross, Triangle]
    }
}
```